# iTextSharp Signed by field

Tags: c#, itext

I am (finally) able to make a signed PDF with my signature, but I can not figure out for the life of me the "Signed by" field.  There are only 3 fields, contact, reason, location.  The other fields are date  and signed by.  I'm not sure how the date gets populated.  You can see I tried a few obvious spots for the signed by field but no soap.

I'm including my code in case it helps other...it took a while to figure this out.

```
static private void SignIt()
{
    // Creating the reader and the stamper
    PdfReader reader = null;
    PdfStamper stamper = null;
    FileStream os = null;

    try
    {
        string sigFileName = "c:\\temp\\signature.jpg";
        string inputFile = "C:\\temp\\mypdf.pdf";
        string outputFile = "C:\\temp\\mypdfsigned.pdf";
        string certFileName = "c:\\temp\\adcl.pfx";
        string certPassword = "adcl214";
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        PdfReader myReader = new PdfReader(inputFile);

        reader = new PdfReader(inputFile);
        os = new FileStream(outputFile, FileMode.Create);

        //Activate MultiSignatures
        stamper = PdfStamper.CreateSignature(reader, os, '\0', null, true);

        //To disable Multi signatures uncomment this line : every new signature will invalidate older ones !
        //stamper = PdfStamper.CreateSignature(reader, os, '\0');


        // Creating the appearance
        PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = stamper.SignatureAppearance;
        Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(275, 25, 500, 100);
        appearance.SetVisibleSignature(rectangle, 1, "Revision " + 1 + "|" + 1);

        appearance.SignatureCreator = "Robert Dejournett, PhD";
        appearance.Reason = "Signed";
        appearance.Location = "MD Anderson Cancer Center";
        appearance.Contact = "Robert Dejournett";
        appearance.Layer2Text = "Signed on " + DateTime.Now;

        appearance.SignatureRenderingMode = iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfSignatureAppearance.RenderingMode.DESCRIPTION;
        PdfTemplate n2 = appearance.GetLayer(2);
        n2.AddImage(AddSignatureImage(sigFileName));

        // generate cert file
        if (!System.IO.File.Exists(certFileName)) GenerateCertToFile(certFileName, certPassword);


        // do needful to get cert info
        Pkcs12Store store = new Pkcs12Store(new FileStream(certFileName, FileMode.Open), certPassword.ToCharArray());

        ICollection<Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate> chain = new List<Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate>();
        String alias = "";
        foreach (string al in store.Aliases)
            if (store.IsKeyEntry(al) && store.GetKey(al).Key.IsPrivate)
            {
                alias = al;
                break;
            }
        AsymmetricKeyEntry pk = store.GetKey(alias);
        foreach (X509CertificateEntry c in store.GetCertificateChain(alias))
            chain.Add(c.Certificate);

        RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters parameters = pk.Key as RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters;

        IExternalSignature pks = new PrivateKeySignature(parameters, DigestAlgorithms.SHA256);
        pks.Sign(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Robert Dejournett"));

        MakeSignature.SignDetached(appearance, pks, chain, null, null, null, 0, CryptoStandard.CMS);

        stamper.Close();
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("GMA: " + ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (reader != null)
            reader.Close();
        if (stamper != null)
            stamper.Close();
        if (os != null)
            os.Close();
    }
}
```

And the generation of the cert.

```
static private void GenerateCertToFile(string certFileName, string password)
{
    RsaKeyPairGenerator kpGenerator = new RsaKeyPairGenerator();
    kpGenerator.Init(new KeyGenerationParameters(new SecureRandom(), 2048));
    // Create a keypair
    AsymmetricCipherKeyPair kp = kpGenerator.GenerateKeyPair();
    // Certificate Generator
    X509V3CertificateGenerator cGenerator = new X509V3CertificateGenerator();
    cGenerator.SetSerialNumber(BigInteger.ProbablePrime(120, new Random()));
    cGenerator.SetSubjectDN(new X509Name("CN=" + "mdanderson.org"));
    cGenerator.SetIssuerDN(new X509Name("CN=" + "ADCL"));
    cGenerator.SetNotBefore(DateTime.Now);
    cGenerator.SetNotAfter(DateTime.Now.Add(new TimeSpan(365, 0, 0, 0))); // Expire in 1 year
    //cGenerator.SetSignatureAlgorithm(HashType.SHA1withDSA.ToString()); // See the Appendix Below for info on the hash types supported by Bouncy Castle C#
    cGenerator.SetSignatureAlgorithm("SHA256WithRSA");

    cGenerator.SetPublicKey(kp.Public); // Only the public key should be used here!
    Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate cert = cGenerator.Generate(kp.Private); // Create a self-signed cert

    // Create the PKCS12 store
    Pkcs12Store store = new Pkcs12StoreBuilder().Build();
    // Add a Certificate entry
    X509CertificateEntry certEntry = new X509CertificateEntry(cert);
    store.SetCertificateEntry(cert.SubjectDN.ToString(), certEntry); // use DN as the Alias.
                                                                     // Add a key entry
    AsymmetricKeyEntry keyEntry = new AsymmetricKeyEntry(kp.Private);
    store.SetKeyEntry(cert.SubjectDN.ToString() + "_key", keyEntry, new X509CertificateEntry[] { certEntry }); // Note that we only have 1 cert in the 'chain'

    // Save to the file system
    using (var filestream = new FileStream(certFileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
    {
        store.Save(filestream, password.ToCharArray(), new SecureRandom());
    }
}
```

Edit - this is what i mean.

[image: Signature example]

Comment: You are not able to see signature image?

Comment: @Rex No, the image works.  There is a field "Signed by" near Contact, Location, etc. that is not populated.  I can't figure out how to populate that field. See the new screenshot.

Comment: Can you share the PDF in question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the certificate to trusted certificates list should resolve this.

I din't had problem with the certificate issue by trusted sites but if the certificate is from unknown source this issue occurs. 
Finally I was able to reproduce this issue by creating an application using your code and automatically resolved after adding the certificate to trusted site.

Comment: Thanks, so you can see the code to generate the cert above in GenerateCertToFile - where would I put the text that I want to appear in "Signed by".  I looked at the X509V3CertificateGenerator  object and I didn't see an obvious spot.  I am populating the SubjectDN and IssuerDN, and I don't see either on the "signed by".  I did import the cert into the certificate store also per your suggestion (which did not resolve the issue).

Comment: I din't modified your code and showing me signed by as "mdanderson.org" which is SubjectDN(but din't show first time since certificate is not a trusted ceritificate). Later  adding the certificate that is generated through code to the Trusted certificates and then re-open the generated PDF resolved me the issue.

Comment: I have uploaded my solution here https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxGB_gOmE_mhc3dkYllhZkFNM00/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Thanks appreciate the help, just one question, where in the store did you add the certificate?  Under Trusted Publishers?

Comment: I'm using Acrobat reader Dc 2017 Release.Open the PDF in acrobat reader -> From the signature properties --> show signer's certificate -> Trust Tab ->        Add to Trusted certificates. The reason we need to do this is to trusted site is that the certificates are generated run time which is unknown.

Comment: Thanks, the problem was I was using Nitro PDF.  There is probably some bug in there that is preventing the "signed by" to display properly.  Confirm it works on Acrobat Reader DC.

Comment: Definetly its an issue with Nitro PDF readr. I tried opening the same PDF in both Acrobat and Nitro but acrobat shows signed by where as nitro doesn't